# Using D3-Geo to plot a shape

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using [d3-geo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-geo) package to plot points and shapes in latitude and longitude space. I would like to plot a simple polygon, triangle, square, star, etc centered on a point location. I would also, if possible, like to plot text at a given [lat,lon].

I currently have the below code working and plotting a ring at the given coords [-40.5, 65.5]. I would, however, like to be able to define different shapes at this location, is there an easy way of doing this without manually defining the shape myself? There is an empty 'properties' field that I'm unable to find any documentation on that could be used? D3-geo documentation and google searches have yielded zilch so far.

```js
let geoGenerator = geoPath()
  .projection(projection)
  .pointRadius(4)
  .context(context); //2d Canvas contect

context.beginPath();
geoGenerator({
  type: "Feature",
  geometry: {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [-40.5, 65.5]
  },
  properties: {}
});
context.stroke();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geojson does not have any property in its specification that specifies the type of symbol (symbol shape, color, size, etc) that should be drawn. Geojson only specifies the geometry (point, line, polygon, etc) of the drawn object in geographic coordinates.

Of course you can use the properties property of a geojson feature to hold symbol data, it just has no effect on the rendering the feature unless you build that functionality yourself.

While geojson doesn't have any specifications for symbology, the geoPath generator in D3 let's you specify one part of a drawn symbol: the radius of a point (as points are dimensionless otherwise). However, other than this, d3-geo doesn't offer any support for drawing specific symbols, it can only project geometry.

To draw a symbol at a specific geographic coordinate, you'll want project the coordinate (`projection([longitude,latitude])`). Now you have a coordinate in pixel values, you can use that coordinate to draw your symbol. You don't want to try and draw the symbol in geographic coordinates as this isn't scalable and it is dependent on projection.

Here's a simple implementation with d3-symbol (I haven't drawn the rest of the world, just two points, but they are projected properly):

```js
var context = d3.select("canvas").node().getContext("2d");

var points = [[-136,63],[-123,50]];

var projection = d3.geoMercator();

var shape = d3.symbol()
     .type(d3.symbolWye)
     .context(context)
     .size(200);

var shapey = function(lonlat) {
   // Get xy Data
   var xy = projection(lonlat);
   // save without translation.
   context.save(); 
   // position symbol:
   context.translate(...xy);
   // Draw symbol:
   context.beginPath();   
   shape();
   context.fill();
   // Remove translation:
   context.restore();
}


points.forEach(shapey);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Of course you could specify your own shapes too, here's a simple square implementation:

```js
var context = d3.select("canvas").node().getContext("2d");

var points = [[-136,63],[-123,50]];

var projection = d3.geoMercator();

var shape = function(xy) {
  var offset = 10;
  var x = xy[0];
  var y = xy[1];
  context.beginPath();
  // draw a sqaure:
  context.moveTo(x-offset,y-offset);
  context.lineTo(x-offset,y+offset);
  context.lineTo(x+offset,y+offset);
  context.lineTo(x+offset,y-offset);
  context.lineTo(x-offset,y-offset);
  context.fill();
  context.strokeStyle = "steelblue";
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.lineCap = "square"
  context.stroke();
}

var shapey = function(lonlat) {
   // Get xy Data
   var xy = projection(lonlat);
   // save without translation.
   shape(xy);

}


points.forEach(shapey);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Of course you could get a lot fancier in these basic functions, but for the purposes of demonstration they should be sufficient.

Comment: thanks @Andrew Reid, exactly what I was looking for.